# PowerQuery - Forecast from table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, forecasting

I am trying to create a forecast (single table) for departments to input their assumptions on spending in a single table. Instead of entering amounts for every single month, I would like the user to enter the amount, frequency, start date, and end date for each category. To illustrate, see below the table with some sample data. [image: Sample Data]

This is the result in Power Query (or Power BI) I am trying to get, which is my understanding of how to be able to run date slicers and filters in a Power BI model when comparing against actuals.
[image: Power Query Data]

If this can't be done with DAX and instead must be done in excel (through look up formulas), how would you structure the formula?

Comment: Appreciate the screenshots- but need to provide more detail with exactly what your Q is - you specify what the user should enter, great, and show sample data, also good, which part do you need assistance with (recreation of your table with those inputs?).  What value/purpose does Power Query info add to this ? Is it necessary/must I worry about that?  Sample soln with some attempt of formula in excel would be great.  also good is recreating the tables using table formatting guideline to spare time this side in typing everything from your screenshot out again.

Comment: You can do this with power query M code.

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld for the heads up. As a non-developer with some experience writing VBA code for excel, do you have any recommended functions? The procedure for each line will be as follows:

1. For each line, plot the value into a matrix (similar to the 2nd screenshot) where the spend amount will fall for each month. 
2. If there is no end date, assume the end date will be the today's date + 5 years. Transform this date to end-of-month. (this way, we are forecasting out by 5 years)
3.If the spend happens quarterly or monthly or semi-annually, have the monthly value plot every nth value

Comment: In Power Query I would create a column with a list of applicable dates for each row; then expand that column into new rows and Pivot on it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a PQ example that creates what you show as your desired table given what you show as your input:

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to better understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table9"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"G/L", Int64.Type}, {"Dimension", type text}, {"Description", type text}, 
        {"Amount", Int64.Type}, {"Repeat Every", type text}, {"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}}),

//Last possible date as Today + 5 years (to end of month)
    lastDt = Date.EndOfMonth(Date.AddYears(Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),5)),

//Generate list of all possible dates for a given row using List.Generate function
    allDates = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "allDates", each let 
            lastDate = List.Min({lastDt,[End Date]}),
            intvl = {1,3,6}{List.PositionOf({"Monthly","Quarterly","Semi Annual"},[Repeat Every])}
        in 
            List.Generate(
                ()=> [Start Date],
                each _ <= lastDate,
                each Date.EndOfMonth(Date.AddMonths(_,intvl)))),

//Remove unneeded columns and expand the list of dates
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(allDates,{"Repeat Every", "Start Date", "End Date"}),
    #"Expanded allDates" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "allDates"),

//Sort to get desired output
//  Date column MUST be sorted to ensure correct order when pivoted
//  Other columns sorted alphanumerically, but could change the sort to reflect original order if preferred.
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded allDates",{
        {"allDates", Order.Ascending}, 
        {"G/L", Order.Ascending}, 
        {"Dimension", Order.Ascending}}),

//Pivot the date column with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(
            Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {
                {"allDates", type text}}, "en-US"), 
            List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"allDates", type text}}, "en-US")[allDates]), 
                "allDates", "Amount")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

**Original Data**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

Comment: OUTSTANDING!!! Thank you Ron. I am puzzled how I didnt check in sooner.